# Suppose you draw a five-card hand randomly from the deck and get four cards that that would make a straight if you could replace the fifth card....

Tags: probability

Suppose you draw a five-card hand randomly from the deck and get four cards that that would
make a straight if you could replace the fifth card. (e.g. J 10 9 8 3 or K 7 6 4 3). If you are
allowed to discard the fifth card and draw one at random from the remaining 47 cards in the
deck, what is the probability that your modified hand will be a straight?

There is replacement, but I can't figure it out. I thought it's just choosing 1, but I know it's not that simple since there are many cases to consider.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: Depends on whether you are trying to fill an inside straight or an outside straight. Depends also in some cases on whether Ace can count as low.

Comment: Will the discarded card be shuffled back into the deck before drawing a replacement?  Or is it impossible to redraw the exact same card you discarded?

Comment: This is all the information I am provided with regarding this. My thoughts are I am drawing one card from the deck that only has one option of being correct.

Comment: If you have for example a $5,7,8,9$ there are $4$ "good" cards. If you have a $6,7,8,9$ there are $8$ good cards.

Answer (score 0):

For an inside straight draw or a straight draw where one of the cards being kept is an ace, of the $47$ remaining cards, exactly four of them will be "good."  This gives the probability $\frac{4}{47}$.

For an outside straight draw, of the $47$ remaining cards, exactly eight of them will be "good."  This gives the probability $\frac{8}{47}$

For example,  the hand $A\spadesuit~2\heartsuit~4\clubsuit~5\clubsuit~9\heartsuit$, you will discard the $9\heartsuit$ and hope to get any of $3\spadesuit,~3\clubsuit,~3\heartsuit,~3\diamondsuit$ with probability of success $\frac{4}{47}$.

On the other hand, if the hand was something like $A\clubsuit~5\heartsuit~6\spadesuit~7\spadesuit~8\diamondsuit$, you will discard the $A\clubsuit$ and will get a straight with any of the following new cards: $4\spadesuit,~4\clubsuit,~4\heartsuit,~4\diamondsuit,~9\spadesuit,~9\clubsuit,~9\heartsuit,~9\diamondsuit$ with probability of success $\frac{8}{47}$.

If the question does not specify which type of straight you are trying to fill, you might assume that an "almoststraight" is picked uniformly at random and condition the probabilities based on which category it falls under.